# Is it possible to Read/Write memory to another process in Lua?

Tags: windows, memory, process, lua, love2d

I'm trying to find a way to edit/hack the memory of an external windows process using Lua, specifically in a [LÖVE2D](https://www.love2d.org/) program.

I was able to do it in Python using ctypes with ReadProcessMemory(). Is there something equivalent to this available for Lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since love2d is using LuaJIT, you may be able to use FFI to get access to ReadProcessMemory function. Here is an [example of how this may look](http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/ReadMemory-crash,2) using [LuaJIT FFI](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html) on Windows.

Comment: Definitely seems to be what I'm looking for. That example is a bit beyond my understanding though. Do you know where I could find a simpler example that just reads a byte of data from a process? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should be able to copy that example and use it almost "as is". `rMemory` and `ReadMemory` do the work and all the rDWORD, rBYTE, and their friends are just convenient wrappers around `rMemory`. You can just call `rMemory` and see if it works for you.